# nested for_each in terraform for hash data block

Tags: terraform

I am a newbie to terraform and an issue. I have network resource to create, each network has its own set of values, data structure looks like this

```json
            "key": "network_data",
            "value": {
                "FT1": {
                    "location": "a",
                    "desc": "Network",
                    "vlan": 101,
                    "IPPool_IPVer": "IPv4",
                    "IPPool_name": "IP Pool",
                    "IPPool_desc": "IP Pool",
                    "IPPool_BaseIP": "x",
                    "IPPool_Netmask": "/24",
                    "IPPool_DefaultRoute": "x",
                    "IPPool_Source_BaseIP": "x",
                    "IPPool_Source_Count": "10",
                    "no_proxy": "x"
                }
            }
```

this data is passed to variables.tf

```
variable "network_data" {
  type    = map(object({
  desc       = string
  location   = string
  vlan       = string
  IPPool_name = string
  IPPool_desc = string
  IPPool_IPVer = string
  IPPool_BaseIP = string
  IPPool_Netmask = string
  IPPool_DefaultRoute = string
  IPPool_Source_BaseIP = string
  IPPool_Source_Count = string
}))
  default = {}
}
```

and resource structure is module based
module tf is like

```
module "network_configuration" {
  source = "./modules/network_configuration"
    
  network_hash                 = var.network_data
  ........
}
```

which calls up resource
resource is like

```
resource .......... {
  for_each    = var.network_hash
  name        = each.value.key        
  description = each.value.value.desc 
  location    = each.value.location
  vlan        = each.value.vlan
  ip_pool {
    name          = each.value.IPPool_name #vMotion IP Pool name
    description   = each.value.IPPool_desc #IP Pool for vMotion
    ip_ver        = each.value.IPPool_IPVer
    base_ip       = each.value.IPPool_BaseIP
    netmask       = each.value.IPPool_Netmask
    default_route = each.value.IPPool_DefaultRoute
    sources {
      base_ip = each.value.IPPool_Source_BaseIP
      count   = each.value.IPPool_Source_Count 
    }
    ................
  }
}
```

I need to pass on values that I build on variables.tf to resource but I keep getting error

> Error: Unsupported attribute on modules/network_configuration/main.tf line 16, in resource "hpegl_metal_network" "pnet": 16: name = each.value.key ├──────────────── │ each.value is object with 11 attributes This object does not have an attribute named "key". Error: Unsupported attribute on modules/network_configuration/main.tf line 17, in resource "hpegl_metal_network" "pnet": 17: description = each.value.value.desc ├──────────────── │ each.value is object with 11 attributes

..........

Did change resource and added locals and flaten to get that data but it is landing in another error

> ```
> locals {
>   pr_net = flatten([
>     for network_key, network in var.network_hash : [
>       for pr_net_name, net_details in network : {
>         network_key       = network_key
>         net_name          = pr_net_name
>         desc              = net_details.value.desc
>         .....
>       }
>     ]
>   ])
> }
>
> output "pr_net" {
>   value = local.pr_net
> }
> ```

but I am getting another error which looks like it is not able to access data

> Error: Unsupported attribute
> on modules/network_configuration/main.tf line 19, in locals:
> 19:         desc              = net_details.value.desc
> Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Comment: It seems that a mandatory key (name conveniently `key`) is missing from the value you are assigning to the variable. This is because the variable definition has the `key` as mandatory: `key        = string`.

Comment: that key was a typo from my end have removed it

Comment: But what is the error then? Did it change after removing the `key`?

Comment: Is the JSON data passed to the variable correct now or it's different to what it was originally set to?